# OS X El Capitan 10.11.3 Java 8 FileDialog doesn't open

Tags: java, macos, swing, awt, finder

I faced with issue during invoking java.awt.FileDialog with next snippet of code. OS X spinner is constantly spinning and nothing change (Finder doesn't open)

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    primaryStage.setTitle("CSV Parser");
    Button button = new Button();
    button.setText("Import Translations");
    button.setOnAction(event -> {
        String openFile = openFile();
        System.out.println("Open file " + openFile);
    });

    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    vbox.setSpacing(8);
    vbox.getChildren().add(button);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static String openFile() {

    JFrame parentFrame = getJFrame("JFrame");
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");

    if (osName.toLowerCase().contains("mac")) {
        FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(parentFrame);

        FilenameFilter csvFilter = (dir, name) -> name.endsWith(".csv");
        fileDialog.setFilenameFilter(csvFilter);
        fileDialog.setFile("*.csv");
        fileDialog.setMode(FileDialog.LOAD);
        String dirHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
        fileDialog.setDirectory(dirHome);
        fileDialog.setVisible(true);

        boolean isShowing = fileDialog.isShowing();

        if (isShowing) {
            File fileToOpen = new File(fileDialog.getFile());
            String path = fileToOpen.getAbsolutePath();
            parentFrame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(parentFrame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
            return path;
        } else {
            parentFrame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(parentFrame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
            return null;
        }

    }

    return null;
}

private static JFrame getJFrame(String name) {
    JFrame parentFrame = new JFrame(name);

    parentFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return parentFrame;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

I need just to have ability to select a file with appropriate extension (not a folder), the appearance of dialog doesn't have a bi sense, but I want to implement it without any **external libs**.
I would be appreciate for any help.

Comment: *"and spinner are spinning"* What 'spinner'? Why not use `JFileChooser` instead of `FileDialog`? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson It doesn't work not with JFileChooser not with FileDialog. Many people reported in SO questions problems with JFileChooser that's why I decided to switch to FileDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog is linked to a new frame (that is not visible)... You should either use `null` argument to dialog's constructor or the reference of the current frame the dialog should be logically linked to.

Comment: I've already tried multiple solutions, it doesn't work not with null not with parent frame. I added method for creation of parent frame to the question. I read post to change lookAndFeel settings to cross platform but it doesn't help

Comment: Then post an MCVE.

Comment: Don't create a JFrame taht is invisible and attach it a Dialog, this is non sense.

Comment: You mixed awt, swing and javafx! It's a mess! At least suppress awt (obsolete). Embed your javafx UI into an approriate JFXPanel and attach a JDialog(swing) to the swing frame.